# Integer Non Linear Program

Tags: combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, binary-programming

I have the following optimization problem.

$$
\max_{x_{ij}}
    \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{M}
          x_{ij} \log_2 \left(\frac{P y_{ij}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{ij}}\right)\\
\text{s.t.}
\sum_{j=1}^{M} \frac{P x_{ij} g_{ij}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{ij}}
                         \leq a_{i}, \forall i,\\
x_{ij} \in \{ 0,1\}
$$

here, $y_{ij},P, g_{ij}, a_{i}$  are real values which are known. How to approach this binary nonlinear problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Throw it into a MINLP solver?

Comment: Suggest me a MINLP solver, moreover, I want to know how it solves the problem

Comment: [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) and [Bonmin](https://projects.coin-or.org/Bonmin) are examples of open source MINLP solvers. (The first one is to find global solutions to non-convex problems, the second one can handle larger problems). There are quite a few other solvers available.